# How can I access a custom HTMLElement Attribute in Typescript

Tags: html, node.js, typescript, properties

I have a parser written in TypeScript, but there are important custom HTML attributes.

```
<span visible-language="en">...</span>
```

How can I read them? I can't just make the `HTMLElement` as a type of `any` and get it as an attribute because the attribute key contains a `-` which isn't allowed in TypeScript / JavaScript Syntax.

I don't use any frameworks, just plain TypeScript.

Comment: [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<span visible-language="en" id="myAttrID">...</span>

const myAttr = document.getElementById("myAttrID") 
let getData = myAttr.getAttribute("visible-language");
```